# How to handle auto-backstab on my rogue party members?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I went mage, but I have heard rogues are OP, but have the problem that they do not auto-backstab. How do I handle this? Is there a way to manually control the rogue to make him backstab turn-based mode, or should I just dump melee rogues if they approach me?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Are you asking how to manually control other characters? Or about how to backstab as a rogue? The way you have currently phrased your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take control of your rogues (or any party member) by simply clicking on their portraits, or using the F1-4 keys.
At any time during the game, you can pause by using the space bar, including during combat. When the game is paused, you can issue orders to your party members.
You can have a tactical view of the battlefield by zooming out.

So, during combat, you can simply pause the game, click on your rogue, click behind an enemy so your rogue will go there when you unpause. When he is there, you can either let him auto-attack, or pause again and order him to use a specific attack.

It is easier to backstab ranged enemies, as they do not move, but melee enemies can be backstabbed too : you just need to prevent them from turning around. Rogues and warriors both have skills to stun the enemy, and mages can freeze them or turn them to stone, preventing them from moving.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways in which you can backstab an opponent.

1. You are attacking him from behind.
2. The opponent is stunned.
3. The opponent is frozen.

So if you manage to stun the enemy very often using your skills or your team mate's skills, then you'll also be able to get the bonus backstab damage without attacking from the back half circle.

Manually positioning the rogue is must if you want to backstab from the back half circle,  as there is no way you can alter the tactics to make the rogue position himself/herself behind the enemies.
Although one thing that is worth noting is that you need to have Coup-De-Grace for easier backstabbing.

Answer (score 0):

[Backstabs](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_mechanics_(Origins)#Backstab) in DAO occur when a rogue attacks anywhere from the back half of the circle of the enemy.

Since you do not want to manually control the rogue, then the only thing you can do is control the target's positioning.

If you are a warrior, you can use skills like [taunt](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Taunt_(Origins)) to turn enemies so their back is exposed to the rogue.  Other than that, manually controlling the rogue is the best way to get them to backstab.  Just move them to the backside of an enemy before attacking with them.